# Java independent block of code

Tags: java, programming-languages

I've been working with Java for a long time but never have come across something like this.
I would like to know what it does and why it is not an error.

```
public class Foo{

 private int someVariable;

 {
    doSomething();
 }

 public Foo(){
 }

 private void doSomething(){
    // Something is done here
 }

}
```

I would like to know what the purpose of the individual block is which contains a call to "doSomething()".
Its just a skeleton code. The actual code that I came across is at http://www.peterfranza.com/2010/07/15/gwt-scrollpanel-for-touch-screens/

Comment: Thanks both of u... That was really helpful... Was clueless before...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's a (non-static) initializer block. It is documented in the official tutorial [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html):

> **Initializing Instance Members**
>
> Normally, you would put code to initialize an instance variable in a constructor. There are two alternatives to using a constructor to initialize instance variables: initializer blocks and final methods.
>   Initializer blocks for instance variables look just like static initializer blocks, but without the static keyword:
>
> ```
> {
>     // whatever code is needed for initialization goes here
> }
> ```
>
> The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor. Therefore, this approach can be used to share a block of code between multiple constructors.

---

Here is a simple demo:

```
public class Test {

    {
        System.out.println("Initializer block");
    }

    Test() {
        System.out.println("Constructor 1");
    }

    Test(int i) {
        System.out.println("Constructor 2");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
        System.out.println("---");
        new Test(1);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Initializer block
Constructor 1
---
Initializer block
Constructor 2
```

---

You may find this useful when for instance adding a `JLabel` to panel:

```
panel.add(new JLabel() {{ setBackground(Color.GREEN); setText("Hello"); }});
```

---

**Under the hood:**

The bytecode of the initializer block is literally copied into each constructor. (At least by Suns javac and the eclipse compiler:

```
Test();
  Code:
    0:  aload_0
    1:  invokespecial
    4:  getstatic #2;
    7:  ldc #3;           //String "Initializer block"
    9:  invokevirtual #4; //Method PrintStream.println:(String;)V
   12:  getstatic #2;
   15:  ldc #5;
   17:  invokevirtual #4;
   20:  return

Test(int);
  Code:
    0:  aload_0
    1:  invokespecial #1;
    4:  getstatic #2;
    7:  ldc #3;           //String "Initializer block"
    9:  invokevirtual #4; //Method PrintStream.println:(String;)V
   12:  getstatic #2;
   15:  ldc #6;
   17:  invokevirtual #4;
   20:  return
```

Comment: Note that it runs *before* the constructor code, so don't depend on things done in the constructor(s).

Answer (score 7):

That's an initializer block, which is copied into all constructors for the class.